# Using backreference to refer to a pattern rather than actual match

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a regex which would match a (not necessarily repeating) sequence of text blocks, e.g.:

`foo,bar,foo,bar`

My initial thought was to use backreferences, something like

`(foo|bar)(,\1)*`

But it turns out that this regex only matches `foo,foo` or `bar,bar` but not `foo,bar` or `bar,foo` (and so on).

Is there any other way to refer to a part of a pattern?

In the real world, `foo` and `bar` are 50+ character long regexes and I simply want to avoid copy pasting them to define a sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a decent regex flavor you could use `(foo|bar)(?:,(?-1))*` or the like.
But Java does not support subpattern calls.

So you end up having a choice of doing String replace/format like in ajx's answer, or you could condition the comma if you know when it should be present and when not. For example:

```
(?:(?:foo|bar)(?:,(?!$|\s)|))+
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could build your regex bit by bit in Java, as in:

```
String subRegex = "foo|bar";
String fullRegex = String.format("(%1$s)(,(%1$s))*", subRegex);
```

The second line could be factored out into a function. The function would take a subexpression and return a full regex that would match a comma-separated list of subexpressions.

Comment: I can't really do that (see my comment under Matt's answer). But if there is no clean way to refer to a pattern part like this, I'll just have live with it.

Answer (score 0):

The point of the back reference is to match the actual text that matches, not the pattern, so I'm not sure you could use that.

Can you use quantifiers like:

```
    String s= "foo,bar,foo,bar";
            String externalPattern = "(foo|bar)"; // comes from somewhere else
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(externalPattern+","+externalPattern+"*");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    boolean b = m.find();
```

which would match 2 or more instances of foo or bar (followed by commas)

Comment: My problem is that regexes are defined externally and Pattern is compiled statically. Your approach could possibly work, but it does not verify if the comma is absent after the last occurrence and present in between others.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but can't you just get your external pattern in a variable and plug it into the pattern - see edited version above.

Comment: The thing is, I can't. There's a legacy framework which validates things based on a defined regex and different object types have different regexps assigned. Using special mechanism just for one type of data would be unacceptable. Thanks for your input anyway.